# Undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

My app seems to randomly be throwing a "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass" error when users are trying to update their profile.

But what's weird is it's saying the error happens on update, but the error line is actually in a view.

Full error:

```
users#update (ActionView::TemplateError) "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass"

On line #52 of app/views/users/edit.html.erb

Line 52: <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@networks_domestic, 'id', 'name', @user.network_id) %>
```

And here are the params from a recent error:

```
{"user"=>{"email_notify"=>"email@example.com", "network_id"=>"", 
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "mobile"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"email"=>"email@example.com"}, "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put", "id"=>"5089", 
"controller"=>"users"}
```

Honestly not sure where to even start looking. I've had a user say he can update the same info from IE but not from Firefox. And when I use their same info I'm able to update without issue. So, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Best guess...

Your edit function properly defines `@networks_domestic` so everything is great until you encounter an error in the update function and call `render :action => "edit"`.

Render does not call the edit function but rather just renders the edit view. So, in the case of a failed update you will have to define `@networks_domestic` before returning from update.

So say, for example, you have the following:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @networkd_domestic = [...]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:notice] = "User was successfully updated."
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_users_url) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

You will get the error you are describing because `@networkd_domestic` is not defined in the error condition in the update function.

Add `@networkd_domestic = [...]` before the edit render and you should be good.

Comment: hi @tony-fontenot, your suggestion worked for me also. Thanks

Comment: 3 years later... and still saved me a lot of valuable time :). Thanks

Comment: This is precisely the issue I came across. Thanks! Is there an approach to set @networkd_domestic in one place instead of in both edit and update?

Comment: @EricC - Set it in a method and use a before_filter callback referencing that method.

Answer (score 6):

Is `@networks_domentic` getting set properly in the controller?  Add `<%= @networks_domestic.inspect %>` right before line 52 and see what you get.  Check for `@networkd_domestic.nil?` in the controller and make sure you don't send `nil` to the view.

EDIT:

If you look at the source for [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001628) you will see that it is calling `map` on the collection you pass (@networks_domestic in this case).